# How can i remove a specific <li> after clicking on the button?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to make a To-Do List. When I am trying to remove the I am not able to do it at all. I don't know how to run function removeBtn()

```
var input = document.getElementById("task");
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

function newElement(){
        var node = document.createElement("li");
        node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        var delButton = document.createElement("button");
        delButton.innerHTML = 'Done';
        node.appendChild(delButton);
        delButton.addEventListener('click', removeBtn);
        ul.appendChild(node).classList.add("remList");
        input.value ='';
}

function checkLength(){
    if (input.value.length != 0){
        newElement();   
    }
    else {
        alert('Empty');
        }
}


function removeBtn(){
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("remList");
    ul.removeChild("remList");
}

button.addEventListener("click", checkLength);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to selecting a *single* element to remove, you need to tie the correct `.remList` to be removed with the button listener. If you want the created `node` to be removed when the `delButton` is clicked, you need to connect `node` to the listener somehow. One option is:

```
// ...
node.appendChild(delButton);
delButton.addEventListener('click', () => node.remove());
ul.appendChild(node).classList.add("remList");
// ...
```

(no need for a separate `removeBtn` function at all)

Comment: hey that worked but could you please explain me 
() => node.remove()

Comment: `node` references the element created in that call of `newElement`. `node.remove()` removes that node from the DOM. `() =>` is an arrow function (here, same as a standard function, just with shorter, terser syntax).

Answer (score 0):

**[`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** returns a **[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** collection of elements. If you want to remove an individual one, you can access the collection like an array:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("remList");
ul.removeChild(list[0]); // Remove the first `.remList` child
```

Comment: hey i tried but if I will 
ul.removeChild(list[0]);
this will only delete the first element of the UL, but if want to delete a specific <li>
that will not happen.

Comment: `[0]` references the first element, which I used as an example. You can substitute this with `[1]` to delete the second, `[2]` to delete the third, and so on. You could even pass through a variable into the array if you really wanted,  depending on how you want to denote which element should be deleted.